# HTML Scraper for Plex downloads page

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a scraper in Python 3 using [Beautiful Soup 4](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org) to retrieve the latest version of [Plex Media Server](https://plex.tv) from https://plex.tv, and I'd like some feedback on how to improve it.

The HTML the parser is to be used on can be found at [here](https://plex.tv/downloads) (the section of code that downloads the HTML itself is not included in the parser).

This is the first time I've written any type of scraper / parser, and I feel my current code is rather messy with some parts being partially redundant.

**parser.py**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from os import path
import os
import re

from .version import PlexVersion


class PlexVersionParser(object):
    def __init__(self, html):
        self._html = html
        self._soup = BeautifulSoup(self.html, 'html.parser')
        self._versions = []

    @property
    def html(self):
        return self._html

    @property
    def soup(self):
        return self._soup

    @property
    def versions(self):
        return self._versions

    def _create_version(self, version_string, platform, name, address):
        version_string = 'Unknown' if version_string is None else version_string
        platform = 'Unknown' if platform is None else platform
        name = 'Unknown' if name is None else name
        address = 'Unknown' if address is None else address

        version = PlexVersion(version_string, platform, name, address)
        self.versions.append(version)

    def _parse_download_link(self, platform, name, address):
        platform = re.sub(r'^Plex Media Server for ', '', platform)
        name = re.sub(r'^Download ?', '', name)

        if len(name) == 0:
            name = None

        url = urlparse(address)
        path_pieces = path.normpath(url.path).split(os.sep)

        self._create_version(path_pieces[2], platform, name, address)

    def _parse_download_links(self, title, links, prefix=None):
        for link in links:
            name = link.text if prefix is None else prefix + ' ' + link.text
            address = link['href']

            self._parse_download_link(title, name, address)

    def _parse_tab(self, tab):
        title = tab.find(class_="title").text
        linkParent = tab.find(class_="pop-btn", recursive=False)

        if linkParent is None:
            linkParent = tab.find(class_="os", recursive=False)

            for link in linkParent.findAll("li"):
                subTitle = link.find("h3").text
                subLinkParent = link.find(class_="pop-btn", recursive=False)
                subLink = subLinkParent.findAll("a", recursive=False)
                self._parse_download_links(title, subLink, subTitle)
        else:
            links = linkParent.findAll("a", recursive=False)
            self._parse_download_links(title, links)

    def _parse_tabs(self, tabs):
        for tab in tabs:
            self._parse_tab(tab)

    def _parse_section(self, section):
        tabs = section.findAll("div", id=re.compile("tabs-[0-9]+"))
        self._parse_tabs(tabs)

    def _parse_sections(self):
        sections = self.soup.findAll("div", id=re.compile("pms-.*"))

        for section in sections:
            self._parse_section(section)

    def parse(self):
        self._parse_sections()
```

**version.py**

```
def _parse_version(version_string):
    pieces = version_string.split('.')

    if len(pieces) != 5:
        raise ValueError('invalid version string')

    major_version = int(pieces[0])
    minor_version = int(pieces[1])
    patch_version = int(pieces[2])
    pre_release_version = int(pieces[3])
    build_metadata = pieces[4]

    return (major_version,
            minor_version,
            patch_version,
            pre_release_version,
            build_metadata)


class SemanticVersion(object):
    def __init__(self, version_string):
        self._version = _parse_version(version_string)

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self._version

    @property
    def major_version(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def minor_version(self):
        return self[1]

    @property
    def patch_version(self):
        return self[2]

    @property
    def pre_release_version(self):
        return self[3]

    @property
    def build_metadata(self):
        return self[4]

    def __str__(self):
        return '.'.join(map(str, self.version))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.version[index]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return all([self[k] == other[k] for k in range(3)])

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self == other:
            return False

        return not any([self[k] <= other[k] for k in range(3)])


class PlexVersion(SemanticVersion):
    def __init__(self, version_string, platform, name, address):
        super().__init__(version_string)

        self._platform = platform
        self._name = name
        self._address = address

    @property
    def platform(self):
        return self._platform

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def address(self):
        return self._address

    def __str__(self):
        version = super().__str__()

        return '{} {} v{}'.format(self.platform, self.name, version)
```

My question is mainly about `parser.py`, but any feedback on my semantic version implementation is very welcome.

The main "irks" I have with my parser are the following:

- The `_parse_tab` method handles the special `os` class case in a way I'm not too fond of. However, I am not sure on any other ways of handling it.
- The way `_create_version` handles `None` cases looks rather verbose to me, but I don't know of a better way of creating a "default" value.

Answer (score 2):

They might have change the format in the meantime, at least I couldn't
find the correct invocation.  Regardless, that doesn't we can't say
something about the code.

For your two irks:

- If the `os` class requires it I don't see a particular problem with
  it.
- `... if x is None else x` - that's more compactly written as `... or
  'Unknown'` as long as it's fine that more falsy values will be
  dropped.  Even then I'd perhaps create a list and `map` over it, or
  create a helper function, e.g.:

  ```
  def _create_version(self, version_string, platform, name, address):
      self.versions.append(PlexVersion(*['Unknown' if x is None else x for x in [version_string, platform, name, address]))
  ```

  or

  ```
  def _create_version(self, version_string, platform, name, address):
      self.versions.append(PlexVersion(*[x or 'Unknown' for x in [version_string, platform, name, address]])
  ```

Some other remarks:

- The names mix styles between camel-case and underscores - choose one
  and stick with it, even if external APIs don't adhere to your style.
- If you really care enough to call `re.compile`, move them into
  constants such that they're only initialised once.
- The API is weird to me:  Is there ever a reason that you wouldn't call
  `parse` on this parser object?  Do you really need access to fields
  except for the `versions` results?  Oh and the last bit:  Why is this
  a class?  I get that it might be useful to organise things, but all
  this could be plain functions as well.
- With regards to the `version.py` file, consider being more descriptive
  with the errors, i.e. indicate that a valid one consists of five
  parts.  Also consider `map(int, pieces[:3])` or something to shorten
  the code - in many cases some clever unpacking, or a functional
  approach can result in drastically more compact code.
- IMO the version classes are overkill, take a look at
  [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/compare-version-strings)
  to reuse some existing ones.